# How to set the permission to access Linked In profile in google Appscript fetchURL

Tags: google-apps-script

### Code

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(profileurl);
Logger.log(response);

---

Error
Jun 8, 2022, 8:31:58 PM Error   Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
at onEdit(Code:93:35)

Comment: onEdit is a simple trigger and simple triggers cannot do anything that requires permission.   UrlFetchApp.fetch() requires this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Comment: Try using an installable onEdit trigger. Preferably change the name to something other than onEdit and remember all functions must have unique names in a given project.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cooper mentioned, there are some [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) with simple triggers like `onEdit`. Simple triggers can't access services that require authorization, like `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.

The workaround would be to rename your function to something else and create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) from your Apps Script project > 'Triggers' > 'Add Trigger'.